# when my xamarin form app run, it's has stopped?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I create a blank app in xamarin form for Android. when i run blank app in emulator thas work exactly, but when add Xamarin.Form.GoogleMaps to my page and run in emulator show error!
error message = "Application has stopped"
I did the following to add Xamarin.Form.GoogleMaps . 
1- download latest version Xamarin.Form.GoogleMaps from Nuget.
2- Add
`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="my api key" />` to AndroidManifest.xml
3- add all permission i need! list of permission
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />`
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />`
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />`
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

4- add `xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"` to my page

5- and add `<maps:Map VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>`

Friends, how can I solve this problem of closing the app?

Comment: have you looked at the logs?

Comment: @Jason no, how can i see the logs?

Comment: look at the "Application Ouput" window in VS, or use the Android tools to view the device logs

Comment: @Jason I saw the logs, but since I'm a newbie, I can't figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the plugin initialization in the Android project.

```
using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Android;
namespace App.Droid
{
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
            // more stuff here...
            var platformConfig = new PlatformConfig
            {
               BitmapDescriptorFactory = new CachingNativeBitmapDescriptorFactory()
            };
            Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState, 
            platformConfig); // initialize for Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps
            }
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't find namespace `CachingNativeBitmapDescriptorFactory()`

Comment: I found the code of this command in address [link](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/blob/master/XFGoogleMapSample/Droid/CachingNativeBitmapDescriptorFactory.cs), but unfortunately the software still closes

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can download the android studio and check the log in the emulator to find what type of error appears and causes the app crash.

In addition, there is already a sample in the github for this nuget package, have you tried that?

Finally, at the 4th step, you not only need to add these permissions into the AndroidManifest.xml, but also need the user to grant the dangerous permissions such as the location permission by himself.

So you can do a run-time permission check and request the permission according to the official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android